# Define Transformer for Table in Cucumberjs

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs

Having the following Scenario

```
Scenario: Mutate multiple User Skills at the same time
    Given the follogin "User Skills":
      | ID | name     | level |
      | 1  | Pilot    | A     |
      | 1  | Sealer   | B     |
      | 2  | Pilot    | A     |
      | 2  | Sealer   | B     |
    When I send "Update Users Skills Mutation"
    Then the "Users" must contain the following "Skills" correspondingly:
      | ID | name     | level |
      | 1  | Pilot    | A     |
      | 1  | Sealer   | B     |
      | 2  | Pilot    | A     |
      | 2  | Sealer   | B     |
```

How can I define a parameter type that match the table?

```
defineParameterType({
   name: 'user skill table',
   regexp: ???,
   transformer: (table) =>{
      return world.createSkillFromTable(table)
   }
})
```

In [The Ruby docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Step-Argument-Transforms#transforming-tables) is a match for data tables like `/^table:column1,column2$/`, but I can find a way to match tables in CucumberJS, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to handle tables in a cucubmer-js step definition.

Using your first `Given` step as an example, the first parameter would be "User Skills", the second paramter will be an object that holds your table, with its (case-sensitive) keys taken from the table header.

```
Given(/the following "(.*)":$/, function (type, table){        
    const rows = table.hashes();
    rows.forEach( (row) => {
        console.log("ID:", row.ID);
    });        
);
```

See [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/data_table_interface.md) for other possible ways of retrieving data from the table parameter.